# How do you reference a second sheet within a single function?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to clear data from two sheets within the same "master" sheet. I found a function that works to clear content from the first sheet referenced. I can't figure out how to call the other sheet and clear content from that with the same function using the onEdit trigger. I am using a checkbox to clear content. Here is the working code for clearing content on the first sheet.

````
  var ss = e.source;
  var activeSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = e.range;


  if (activeSheet.getName() == "SIGNATURE BATCHES" && cell.getA1Notation() == "E6" && cell.isChecked()){
    // Clear CellS
    activeSheet.getRange("E10:14").clearContent();
    activeSheet.getRange("E19:E23").clearContent();
    activeSheet.getRange("E27:E33").clearContent();
    activeSheet.getRange("E37:E41").clearContent();
    activeSheet.getRange("E44:E48").clearContent();
    activeSheet.getRange("E51:E55").clearContent();
    activeSheet.getRange("E59:E63").clearContent();
    activeSheet.getRange("E66:E70").clearContent();
    activeSheet.getRange("E74:E77").clearContent();
    activeSheet.getRange("E81:E84").clearContent();
    
    // reset checkbox
    cell.setValue(false); 
  }};```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can set another variable and apply the process you desire inside your code. For example:

```
var othersheet = ss.getSheetByName("Other Sheet")

othersheet.getRange("E10:14").clearContent()
```

Answer (score 0):

In your script, it seems that the contents of multiple ranges are cleared by the scripts of multiple lines. In this case, when RangeList is used, the script can be simple and the process cost of the script can be also reduced a little. And also, I thought that this can be useful for your expected situation of `how to call the other sheet and clear content from that with the same function using the onEdit trigger`. When this is reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```js
activeSheet.getRange("E10:14").clearContent();
activeSheet.getRange("E19:E23").clearContent();
activeSheet.getRange("E27:E33").clearContent();
activeSheet.getRange("E37:E41").clearContent();
activeSheet.getRange("E44:E48").clearContent();
activeSheet.getRange("E51:E55").clearContent();
activeSheet.getRange("E59:E63").clearContent();
activeSheet.getRange("E66:E70").clearContent();
activeSheet.getRange("E74:E77").clearContent();
activeSheet.getRange("E81:E84").clearContent();
```

#### To:

```js
var a1Notations = ["E10:14", "E19:E23", "E27:E33", "E37:E41", "E44:E48", "E51:E55", "E59:E63", "E66:E70", "E74:E77", "E81:E84"];
activeSheet.getRangeList(a1Notations).clearContent();
ss.getSheetByName("###sheetName###").getRangeList(a1Notations).clearContent();
```

- Please replace `###sheetName###` with your another sheet name.
- In this case, the active sheet and another sheet are used.
- If you want to use other ranges on another sheet, please prepare a range list for it and use it to `ss.getSheetByName("###sheetName###").getRangeList(a1Notations).clearContent()`.

#### References:

- [getSheetByName(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet?hl=ja#getsheetbynamename)
- [getRangeList(a1Notations)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet?hl=ja#getrangelista1notations)